# If $Y,Z, X_1, X_2$ are r.v. where $X_2$ is a function of $X_1$. If $Y$ and $Z$ are indep. given $X_1, X_2$, is $Y$ and $Z$ are indep. given $X_1$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $Y,Z, X_1, X_2$ are random variables and that $X_2$ is a deterministic function of $X_1$. Then suppose we knew that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent given $X_1, X_2$, such that,

$$
P(Z,Y \mid X_1, X_2) = P(Z\mid X_1, X_2) P(Y\mid X_1, X_2)
$$

Then is it true or can it be proven that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent given just $X_1$, such that,

$$
P(Z,Y \mid X_1) = P(Z\mid X_1) P(Y\mid X_1)
$$
?

Generally it appears that additional conditioning on a function of a random variable makes no difference, so it feels true, but I am not able to prove it.

Comment: It is true, while $Y$ and $Z$ being conditionally independent given $X_2$ need not be true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X_2=f(X_1)$ for some measurable function $f$ then $\sigma (X_1,X_2)=\sigma(X_1)$. Hence the claim is true.

Comment: Thank you, based on the structure of what you have above, it is true this statement holds the other direction? In other words, $Y$ and $Z$ being independent given $X_1$ only implies $Y$ and $Z$ being independent given $X_1, X_2$? thank you!

Comment: Yes, because of the equality of $\sigma(X_1,X_2)$ and $\sigma (X_1)$ the implications in both directions are true.

Answer (score 1):

We know,

P(A/B)=p(A∩B)/p(B)

p(Z∩Y/X1,X2) = p(Z/X1,X2)*p(Y/X1,X2) = $\frac{p(Z,X2/X1) * p(Y,X2/X1)}{(p(X2/X1))^2}$

As X2 is a deterministic function of X1 only, given X1, X2 is a constant.

Therefore, P(X2/X1) = 1 and 
as X2 is a constant p(Z,X2/X1) = p(Z/X1) (Prob of Z,X2 given X1 will depend only on Z)

and p(Y,X2/X1) = p(Y/X1)

$\frac{p(Z,X2/X1) * p(Y,X2/X1)}{(p(X2/X1))^2} = \frac{p(Z/X1) * p(Y/X1)}{(p(X2/X1))^2} = p(Z/X1) * p(Y/X1)$